# Data being encapsulated, cannot pass into another class

Tags: objective-c

I've made a variable(difficulty) in DifficultySelection and when I try to reach this variable from CharacterSelection, the result = 0, so I'm guessing there is a problem with encapsulation somewhere.

**DifficultySelection.h:**

```
@class CharacterSelection;
@interface DifficultySelection : UIViewController
{
    CharacterSelection *charPage;
    UIButton *normalDifficulty;
    int difficulty;

}

- (IBAction)normalDifficulty:(id)sender;

@property (strong) CharacterSelection *charPage;
@property (strong) DifficultySelection *diffPage;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *normalDifficulty;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int difficulty;
@end
```

**DifficultySelection.m:**

```
#import "DifficultySelection.h"
#import "CharacterSelection.h"

@interface DifficultySelection ()  
@end

@implementation DifficultySelection
@synthesize normalDifficulty, charPage, diffPage, difficulty;

- (IBAction)normalDifficulty:(id)sender {
    if (! self.charPage)
        self.charPage = [[CharacterSelection alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.difficulty = 1;
    charPage.diffPage = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.charPage animated:YES];

}
@end
```

**CharacterSelection.h:**

```
#import "DifficultySelection.h"
@class MainGameDisplay;
@class DifficultySelection;

@interface CharacterSelection : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    MainGameDisplay *openGame;
    DifficultySelection *diffPage;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CharacterSelection *charPage;    
@property (strong) DifficultySelection *diffPage;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int difficulty;
@end
```

**CharacterSelection.m:**

```
#import "CharacterSelection.h"
#import "MainGameDisplay.h"

@interface CharacterSelection ()
@end

@implementation CharacterSelection
@synthesize diffPage, charPage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.difficulty = charPage.diffPage.difficulty;
    printf("Diff:%i %i", self.difficulty, diffPage.difficulty);
    //Both of these output 0, encapsulation problem.
}
@end
```

Comment: Difficult to know whether or not you are initialising any of your variables, where's the code that creates objects of these classes?  When does are IBAction get called that sets the difficult variable?

Comment: It's a button so it's clicked. I've placed a printF in the IBaction and it gives the correct difficulty.

Comment: In `normalDifficulty:`, log `self` and `charPage`; then in `-[CharacterSelection viewDidLoad]`, log `self` and `diffPage`

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I'm not quite sure what you meant but this is what I did: NSLog(@"%@ %@", self, charPage");. This is the results I got:<DifficultySelection: 0x847f960> <CharacterSelection: 0x8058b20> and <CharacterSelection: 0x8058b20> <DifficultySelection: 0x847f960>

Comment: Log charPage.diffPage.  Also, make sure that the source "difficulty" is being set non-zero.